# Use of ternary operator instead of if-else in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, idioms

I just came across the following (anonymized) C++ code:

```
auto my_flag = x > threshold;
my_flag ? do_this() : do_that();
```

is this a standard C++ idiom instead of using if-else:

```
if (x > threshold)
{
    do_this();
} 
else
{
    do_that();
}
```

Even though it's only two lines, I had to go back and re-read it to be sure I knew what it was doing.

Comment: yes that is the short form for that

Comment: It could even fit in one line: `x > threshold : do_this() : do_that();`

Comment: This is only a matter of style.
I would prefer the `if-else`, since in almost 99% of cases you don't only want to call a function, but also assign values to variables

Comment: Be careful with the conditional expression. First of all, it's an *expression* and not a statement, as are all the three parts of it. You can't have blocks of statements in the "true" or "false" parts. And the results of the "true" and "false" parts must be of the same type, or types that can be implicitly converted to each other. Also, it's very easy to make messy and unreadable conditional expressions, in which case you should definitely use an `if else` statement.

Comment: You could also learn to use tools like [the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/) to check the assembly code generated from the different codes. Remember to build with optimization enabled, or the compiler might generate different code.

Comment: An expression using `?:` is an *alternative* to an `if`/`else` in some circumstances (e.g. if the results of `do_this()` and `do_that()` have compatible types) but not others.   Where it is a valid alternative, there are advantages and disadvantages either way - including related to readability, like you've noted.     There is no one-size-fits-all choice.

Comment: Using the conditional operator for anything other than choosing between two values is bordering on abuse, and is one of the things that have given it a bad reputation.

Comment: I notice you edited the question to mention that the answers here are better (which I've now rolled back, since that's commentary that shouldn't be in a question). That's fine, the answers still exist here. You *could* flag the post for a merge, but merges are tricky, and I doubt this one will be done. Also, they are duplicates, in that they're asking if the code is valid. If you're actually asking whether this is something that programmers do, or should do, that's opinion based, which is not really suitable for the Q&A format.

Comment: @cigien ok! Thanks for the feedback. I wonder why there exists an idiom flag? Surely the existence or otherwise of such isn’t opinion-based?

Comment: That's a good point. I'm not really sure what purpose the [idiom] tag serves. It does look a bit like a "meta tag" to me, based on the description. I'll take a closer look at it, thanks. Update: Ah, it is indeed a [meta-tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403711), and should be cleaned up at some point, if someone has the time, and energy to do so.

Comment: @cigien Cool! Thanks for checking. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In general the conditional operator is not a replacement for an `if-else`.

The most striking difference is that the last two operands of the conditional operator need to have a common type. Your code does not work eg with:

```
std::string do_this() {return {};}
void do_that() {}
```

There would be an error because there is no common type for `void` and `std::string`:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:15:22: error: third operand to the conditional operator is of type 'void', but the second operand is neither a throw-expression nor of type 'void'
   15 |     my_flag ? do_this() : do_that();
      |               ~~~~~~~^~
```

Moreover, the conditional operator is often less readable.

The conditional operator can be used for complicated in-line initialization. For example you cannot write:

```
 int x = 0;
 int y = 0;
 bool condition = true;
 int& ref;                                 // error: must initialize reference
 if (condition) ref = x; else ref = y;     // and even then, this wouldn't to the right thing
```

but you can write

```
 int& ref = condition ? x : y;
```

My advice is to not use the conditional operator to save some key-strokes compared to an `if-else`. It is not always equivalent.

PS: The operator is called "conditional operator". The term "ternary operator" is more general, like unary or binary operator. C++ just happens to have only a single ternary operator (which is the conditional operator).

Comment: I think the compiler will execute less commands with the conditional operator than with an if-else (just another difference)

Comment: @Ivan: I'm not so sure about that, do you have any supporting evidence?

Comment: @Bathsheba I was trying to get it with a simple program. But the compiler is smart enough to generate the same assembly commands!

Comment: @Ivan when the observable behavior is the same, then a good compiler will emit same program, when it isnt the same then comparing the runtime isnt that meaningful

Answer (score 2):

They are indeed broadly equivalent. Note that for the ternary conditional operator, the two branches need to have types that are sufficiently related so that a common type can be imputed for the entire expression<sup>1</sup>. If you have user defined types with conversion operators that have side effects, you can contrive the behaviour of the ternary conditional operator to be really quite different:

```
#include <iostream>

struct do_this
{
    operator int() const
    {
        std::cout << "Pay me a bonus";
        return 0;
    }
};

struct do_that
{
    operator int() const
    {
        std::cout << "Reformat my hard disk";
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    true ? do_this() : do_that();
}
```

Therefore one should regard the `if` block as clearer if the result of the ternary conditional is not required.

---

<sup>1</sup> Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference between if-then and the ternary condition is the intent:

- if-then: **do** something based on the condition
- ternary condition: **return** something based on the condition

So:

```
if (want_to_do_this) {
    do_this();
} else {
    do_that();
}

int result = want_to_get_this? get_this(): get_that();

int my_int_max(int i1, int i2) { return i1 > i2? i1: i2; }
```

I thought this was generally expected, but I didn't see that in the already given answers.

Answer (score -1):

**No it is not a standard replacement of if-else**

But yes it works perfectly well.

For example i have this example c++ code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test1(){
    cout<< "test 1"<<endl;
}
void test2(){
    cout<< "test 2"<<endl;
}

int main() {
    1>2?test1():test2();
}
```

And this is the output

```
test 2
```

This is the same as doing this

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test1(){
    cout<< "test 1"<<endl;
}
void test2(){
    cout<< "test 2"<<endl;
}

int main() {
    if(1>2){
       test1();
    }else{
        test2();
    }
}
```

**But using of if-else block makes it easier to read even though it makes it a bit longer.**

Comment: "it works perfectly well" is too strong. In some situations it works perfectly well, but not in all. As another answer points out, the results of the two expressions have to have a common type. That's because `?:` is an **expression**; it has a value. `if ... else ...` is a statement; it does not have a value.

Comment: @PeteBecker, It may vary according to the requirement but for this, it works perfectly well